# Why can't I initialize getter this way in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, getter, self

I'm a bit confused why I can't initialize a getter this way:

```
@synthesize stack = _stack;

- (NSMutableArray *) stack
{
    if (self.stack == nil) {
        self.stack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self.stack;
}
```

I know that if I replace self.stack with _stack, it will work perfectly fine, but I just don't know why I can't use self.stack. I use self.stack later on in the code without problem though.

Comment: Using self.stack in the getter for stack will result in a loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in following line:

```
if (self.stack == nil)
```

which is equivalent to

```
if ([self stack] == nil)
```

So you're calling your getter method inside itself and that results in infinite recursion. You can remove calling the getter by addressing the ivar itself:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) stack
{
    if (_stack == nil) {
        _stack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return _stack;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`self.stack` calls the getter you are creating. By using `self.stack` inside the getter method, you are creating an infinite loop, which is not desirable.

Answer (score 0):

When calling this line

```
if (self.stack == nil) {
```

it goes back into the exact method and it is created an infinite loop. Just remove the self.

Answer (score 0):

What you've written is equivalent to something like :

```
- (bool) thisIsTrue
{
      if ([self thisIsTrue])
      {
          //
      }
}
```

Obviously the function calls itself *over and over* again, creating an **infinite loop** and leading to a **crash**.